# Oracle procedure saving SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, procedure

As part of a larger procedure I'm trying to write some code, which saves SYSDATE into a variable but I'm running into a problem. I narrowed it down to the following. Can someone please help me out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXX
AS
  l_date_string VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

select into l_date_string '['||TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS')||']' from dual;
 
END;
/
```

Comment: `l_date_string := TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS');`?

Comment: what problem are you running into ? what is the error?

Comment: The syntax is `select 'value' into l_variable from dual;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `PL\SQL` you can just *assign*:

```
BEGIN

...

  l_date_string := '[' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS') || ']'; 

...

END;
```

if you insist on `sql` all you have to do is to *add* `into` after  `select`:

```
BEGIN

...

  -- standard select .. from .. with additional "into"  
  select '[' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS') || ']'
    into l_date_string 
    from dual;

...

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where your issue might be .

```
select '['||TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS')||']' into l_date_string  from dual;
```

notice the change of the `into`.